# Modular arithmetic with coprime numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime. By doing a few concrete examples, I see that the numbers $0,m,2m,3m,\dots,(n-1)m$ get mapped to the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,(n-1)$ in $\operatorname{mod}(n)$. How do I show that when going from $0$ to $(n-1)m \operatorname{mod}(n)$ we trace out the numbers $0\dots(n-1)$ (albeit likely by jumping about) without repeating?

Example: $m=4,n=9$, we get $0,4,8,3,7,2,6,1,5,$

Example $m=10,n=7$, we get $0,3,6,2,5,1,4$.

Comment: Consider if any do repeat and what means about their difference.

Comment: What John said. This is also relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Answer (score 2):

user has already written a good answer.

In this answer, I will add more details.

Suppose that there are integers $s,t$ such that
$$0\leqslant s\lt t\lt n\qquad\text{and}\qquad sm\equiv tm\pmod n$$

Then, there is a positive integer $u$ such that

$$(t-s)m=un$$

Now, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there are integers $a,b$ such that
$$am+bn=1$$

Multiplying the both sides by $(t-s)$ gives
$$a(t-s)m+bn(t-s)=t-s,$$
i.e.
$$aun+bn(t-s)=t-s,$$
i.e.
$$n(au+b(t-s))=t-s$$

Since $n$ divides $(t-s)$, there is a positive integer $w$ such that $t-s=wn$.

Since $t=wn+s$, one has
$$t\lt n\implies wn+s\lt n\implies n+s\leqslant wn+s\lt n\implies n+s\lt n\implies s\lt 0$$
which contradicts $s\geqslant 0$.

Therefore, for every pair $(s,t)$ such that $0\leqslant s\lt t\lt n$,
$$sm\not\equiv tm\pmod n$$

Comment: @PM 2Ring : Thanks for your comment. I added $n(au+b(t-s))=t-s$ which I should have written.

Comment: That definitely makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\exists k\,, 0< k < n$ such that

$$k \cdot m \equiv 0 \pmod n$$

which can't be true by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) since $k<n$.

Then, assuming wlog $k_1\ge k_2$, suppose

$$k_1 \cdot m \equiv k_2 \cdot m \pmod n \iff(k_1-k_2)\cdot m \equiv 0\pmod n$$

which can be true only if $k_1=k_2$.

Comment: How do we know that $k_im$ is coprime with n?

Comment: @matt $k_i$ and $m$ are both coprime with $n$

Comment: If n=6, $k_i=3$, they are not coprime

Comment: @matt I've fixed, we have that $k_i\cdot m$ is not a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, why is $k_im$ not a multiple of n

Comment: @matt because $0<k_i<n$

Comment: I still don't find it obvious, I'm afraid, and I do not know how to show that mathematically.

Comment: @matt I try to revise it in another form.

Comment: Right, so the first part is true because $km-hn$ must be multiples of $d=1$

Comment: But hang on a second, would 0 count as a multiple of 1? Does 0 count as a multiple of any number?

Comment: After checking that 0 is considered to be a multiple of every number, I do not see how that follows from Bezout's identity.

Comment: @matt Yes you are right. The point is that $km$ (with $0<k<n$) can't be a multiple of $n$. Euclid's lemma is the way to see that better.